# Angular - Getting item id and value from a HTML select

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, html-select

I'm using Angular and AngularFire to fetch a list of clients from Firestore. I have displayed them in a HTML dropdown (select).

Upon selecting an item I would like to obtain the `client.id` and `client.name`

So far, this is able to get me the client ID upon selection. What I would also like to get upon selecting an item from the drop down is the `client.name`.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedClient">
   <option *ngFor="let client of clients | async" [value]="client.id"> 
        {{ client.name}} 
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: <option *ngFor="let client of clients | async" [value]="client.name"> Do you want this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the object as value but use [`ngValue`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgSelectOption#ngValue) instead of `value` property in that case since `value` only accepts strings.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedClient">
   <option *ngFor="let client of clients | async" [ngValue]="client">
   <!------------------------------------here-----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-> 
        {{ client.name}} 
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know you could do that. How would I access items of that object in the .ts file. For example.... `console.log(this.selectedClient.client)` (which obviously doesn't work, but hopefully accentuates my point)

Comment: @Que inside ts file you can get it like  `this.selectedClient.name` and `this.selectedClient.id`

Comment: That's what I thought, however, the following error occurs `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'object'` when trying to console log that out. Any ideas?

Comment: @Que : check `console.log(this.selectedClient)`

Comment: @Que : in your ts file declare it like `selectedClient:any;`

Comment: Ah, it was `:any` instead of object. Thanks a lot dude. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass in the whole object instead of just the id.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedClient">
   <option *ngFor="let client of clients | async" [ngValue]="client"> 
        {{ client.name}} 
   </option>
</select>
```

Then you will have access to both properties, `client.id` and `client.name`.

Answer (score 0):

just pass `client` in value of option instead of `client.id`

Comment: While this context may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML File

```
<select (change)="selectedClient($event.target.value)">
   <option *ngFor="let client of clients | async" [value]="client"> 
        {{ client.name}} 
   </option>
</select>
```

In your ts file

```
selectedClient(client){
   console.log(client.id+" "client.name); 
   //here u can access client id and client name and you can do any operations required
}
```